# More than 200 row with mixed date, text inform, want extract only the date and its related PLM-A and KOM

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In my exported excel column, each cell contains mixed text, date, numbers. like below, I want extract only **PLM-A - date - Attended**, and **KOM - date - slides provided**. Is there any VBA code to do so?

```txt
*Keep updated throughout study until handover is completed

Study information:
Expected FPI date - January 2022
Protocol status - Draft attached
Contracted Regions - APAC, EMEA, NA
Contracted Countries - Thailand, Vietnam, Greece, South Africa, Ukraine, United States (Total 11 Sites)

Assigned resources:
Project Lead - Paul Carter
CTM - Rene Ategwa
Site Payments ARA - Monica Lopez Martinez

Key meeting dates:
PLM-A - 12 April 2022 - Attended
KOM - 19 April 2022 - Slides provided
PLM-B - TBD*
```

i tried different formulas such as SEARCH ("PLM-A", S2:S900), it turns out to be "#SPILL"!

or:

```
=FILTER ("XtractFilters!S2:S900",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PLM-A  *",[XtractFilters]Sheet Export [Data]Sheet1! S4:S902)), "?")
```

Which returns only? for all cells?

Comment: Search doesn't allow (or need) wildcards. It searches for the specific string, so including the asterisk in this case. So either remove it, or use MATCH with wildcard.

Comment: What do want to do with the extracted data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want  the results presented.
If you have `365` you can use:

To output in the same column but multiple rows:

```
=LET(
    d, TEXTSPLIT(A1, , CHAR(10)),
    TOCOL(
        XLOOKUP(
            {"PLM-A*", "KOM*"},
            d,
            d,
            "not found",
            2
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

To output in the same row but with multiple columns:

```
=LET(
    d, TEXTSPLIT(A1, , CHAR(10)),
    XLOOKUP(
        {"PLM-A*", "KOM*"},
        d,
        d,
        "not found",
        2
    )
)
```

[image]

To output both in the same cell where you can `WrapText`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(
    CHAR(10),
    ,
    LET(
        d, TEXTSPLIT(A1, , CHAR(10)),
        XLOOKUP(
            {"PLM-A*", "KOM*"},
            d,
            d,
            "not found",
            2
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

If you have multiple cells in one column to process, and you want to output each finding in a pair of columns in the same row, you can try this:

```
=WRAPROWS(
    LET(
        d, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), , A1:A2), , CHAR(10)),
        FILTER(d, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PLM-A", d)) + ISNUMBER(SEARCH("KOM", d)))
    ),
    2
)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your all methods and the TEXTJOIN works best for me and appreciate your genius options

Answer (score 1):

I would make a new VBA function ExtractMeetingData() to extract the desired lines. Here is a example VBA, after you create this you can assign it to a cell to pull the matching value. For example, if your mixed-text data is in column A, and data starts from A4 use =ExtractMeetingData(A4) in B4 and past it the end of the table.

[image]

```
Public Function ExtractMeetingData(cellContent As Range) As String
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim line As String
    Dim output As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    lines = Split(cellContent.Value, vbLf)
    For i = LBound(lines) To UBound(lines)
        line = Trim(lines(i))
        
        ' Check for PLM-A and KOM patterns
        If InStr(1, line, "PLM-A") > 0 Or InStr(1, line, "KOM") > 0 Then
            ' Append to output
            If output <> "" Then output = output & vbLf
            output = output & line
        End If
    Next i
    
    ExtractMeetingData = output
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes(), aKey
    Const SEP_CHAR = " - "
    Const SEARCH_WORD = "PLM-A|KOM" ' Modify as needed
    Set rngData = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData))
    k = 1
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, 1) = UCase(Trim(arrData(i, 1)))
        If Len(Trim(arrData(i, 1))) Then
            ' Split by SEP_CHAR
            aKey = Split(arrData(i, 1), SEP_CHAR)
            ' Key word matching
            If InStr(SEARCH_WORD, aKey(0)) Then
                arrRes(k) = arrData(i, 1)
                k = k + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write output to new sheet
    ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To k - 1)
    Sheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(k - 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
End Sub
```

[image]